# For loop to convert ISO Dates in own Format mixxing up things

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that works. It converts the ISO date into normal date . However on my website I have several objects so I put it in a for loop. But somehow it mixes things up. 
When I choose the date of the last object in the live demo, some other date object suddenly depicts NaN or the day and month get interchanged.
Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let el = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
    if (el[j]) {
        let date = new Date(el[j].textContent);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = ("00" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let day = ("00" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        el[j].textContent = '${day}.${month}.${year}';
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElemensByClassName` is a typo.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but that was not the problem.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML that goes with this?  It would help if we had a [mre].

Comment: Running `new Date(string)` is risky. You mention ISO date, which should work, but if you run that same code again, it may or may not work.

Comment: It may not be _the_ problem but it's a barrier to those who would offer help. If you don't provide a reproducible example, which would include your markup, it's more difficult to help... particularly if you introduce unrelated bugs in your request.

Comment: Im afraid I cannot give the whole html output . Its too much and I signed confidency. But you can ask for specific question or the html form. 
Ok I will try to work around the new Date.

Comment: Nobody is asking that you to violate an NDA. Presumably, you just need a few elements with a "date" class and some date text.

Comment: You're also not using the appropriate quotes for an interpolated string.

Comment: @Bitlord Please read [What should an asker do if they're not able to include source code in their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252977/what-should-an-asker-do-if-theyre-not-able-to-include-source-code-in-their-ques)

Comment: The "date" elements are just containing a date. It looks like this '<h3 class="date" id="date">02.12.2020</h3>' 
If I console log el[j].textContent it throws something like this '
19.02.2020
02.12.2020
aN.aN.NaN
 12.02.2020
 07.02.2020
2 aN.aN.NaN'

Comment: That important detail should be in the question; you just revealed that your dates are stored in a format that `Date` doesn't understand.  That's critical, and is why we're asking for a [mre].

Comment: Ah well thanks ! Now I understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a `00.00.0000` formatted string to the `Date` constructor, it assumes you meant `MM.dd.yyyy`. Since your date format is `dd.MM.yyyy`, the parsing will have the wrong day/month and fail outright for days past the 12th.

```js
console.table([
  "01.01.2020",
  "02.01.2020", 
  "13.01.2020"  
].map(input => ({
  input,
  output: new Date(input).toString()
})));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block;}</style><script>console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false})</script>
```

You can still use your desired format; you'll just need to make sure you don't reprocess the formatted dates. So, once you've applied formatting, add a `date-formatted` class so you can skip those elements in the future, using `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```js
function formatDates() {
  let el = document.querySelectorAll(".date:not(.date-formatted)");
  for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
    if (el[j]) {
      let date = new Date(el[j].textContent);
      date = new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4);    
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let month = ("00" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      let day = ("00" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);      
      el[j].textContent = `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
      el[j].classList.add("date-formatted");
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", formatDates);
```

```html
<div class="date">2019-01-01</div>
<div class="date">2019-02-01</div>
<div class="date">2019-03-01</div>
<button>format dates (click me twice)</button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you and nice trick with the formatted class !